# How to show that $|P(A\cap B)−P(A)P(B)|≤\frac{1}{4}$?

Tags: probability

I am trying to show that
$$
|P(A\cap B)−P(A)P(B)|≤\frac{1}{4}
$$
But I don't see how to begin... If $A$ and $B$ are independent the result is obvious. Can someone give me a hint?